# Apache Forward JSP pages to tomcat

Tags: php, apache, jsp, tomcat

I have Apache Server, in which my website running, but there is some jsp pages in my website. I have to forward my jsp pages and servlet to tomcat. Kindly help me so that I can make it possible.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: this would be better asked at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out mod_proxy:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html